# Problema al guardar modelo Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, inteligencia-artificial

Entrené varios modelos descargados del model zoo de Tensorflow 2, pero cuando los paso a formato .pb con exporter_main_v2.py del object detection de TensorFlow model garden, durante el proceso me alerta con varios Warnings que dicen:

`WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Lambda object at 0x000002B0CDD382C8>, because it is not built.`

La versión de Tensorflow que uso es la 2.4.1

Me falta instalar algo?

Answer (score 1):

Este warning surge cuando tu modelo no tiene un `input_shape` (tamaño de entrada) definido. No es obligatorio definir un tamaño de entrada por lo que en principio no deberías tener ningún problema.

Para chequear si tu modelo tiene un `input_shape` definido puedes hacer:

```
print(model.inputs is None)
```

Todo esto puedes verlo en la [documentación oficial de Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/save_and_load#caveats)

Comment: Hola Alberto, gracias por contestar!
La inferencia en tensorflow de hecho funciona bien, el tema es que quiero exportar el modelo a Openvino y me rebota, imagino que debe ser por eso.
Pensé que el input shape lo sacaba el entrandor del pipeline.config, voy a estudiar el tema!!!